# Execute multiple functions at once

Tags: c, function

I need to make a simple calculator for a school project using only functions.

One of the functions is:

```
double addition(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

And I call it and show the results doing this:

```
printf( "Addition: %.2lf\n", addition(x,y));
```

I have other functions for substraction, multiplication, and division.

I need to perform each one of those separately, and then, perform them all at once.

How can I integrate all of these functions in just one function, like this:

```
printf( "All of the results %.2lf\n", allfunctions(x,y));
```

Is it possible?

I'm trying to avoid doing something like this:

```
printf( "Addition: %.2lf\n", addition(x,y));
printf( "Substraction: %.2lf\n", substraction(x,y));
```

Thanks.

Comment: couldn't you write a function that calls all the functions, and when you want to perform them all at once, call it?

Comment: Your last two lines should be in `allfunctions`, then just call that. LIke it or not, if you want to report *each* result, you have to do just that: *report **each** result*. And yes, you can put them all in a single `printf` if you stack the format string and arguments sufficiently.

Comment: What do you mean by "all at once"? Can you give an example?

Comment: Regarding `printf( "All of the results %.2lf\n", allfunctions(x,y));`" -- What should `allfunctions()` return for various fixed values of `x` and `y`?   Is this really what was intended or can "`allfunctions(x,y);`" all by itself result in the printouts of "`Addition: %.2lf`" (etc)?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by create an `allfunctions(x,y)` and inside the `allfunctions(x,y)` you call another functions that you want to execute. Example:

Function 1: `add(double x, double y) { printf( "Addition: %.2lf\n", x + y ); }`

Function 2: `divide(double x, double y) { printf( "Division: %.2lf\n", x / y ); }`

All functions: `allfunctions(double x, double y) { add(x,y); divide(x,y); }`

Then all you need is calling `allfunctions(x,y)`.

Comment: Welcome too Stack Overflow. It is good to see new contributors. You might like to know that you can retain code formatting by adding four extra spaces at the beginning of each lines of code. Select a block of text and push Ctrl-K to do this quickly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've added backticks around bits of your answer that should look like code, but I'd suggest that in fact you should spread the functions out over 5 lines each.  You've omitted the return type; that's not good.  The functions should probably return the value they're supposed to compute.  Temporarily, I'll allow printing and computation to be mixed in a single function, but it is generally better to keep them separate.  The computation doesn't need to change even if you move from the USA to Japan or Russia; the printing might well need to be changed. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ You need to add the return types, and if the return type is not `void` you need to add the appropriate return statement.  I've no idea what the `allfunctions()` function should return as its return value, but the question does want to print it.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do would be to declare an array of pointers to functions:

```
double (*arith_op[4])(double, double) = {addition, subtraction, multiplication, division};
const char *strings[4] = {"addition", "subtraction", "multiplication", "division"};

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("Result of %s is %.2lf\n", strings[i], arith_op[i](x,y));
}
```

This is one way of handling your problem.

Comment: While it is an appropriate solution, this sounds to me like it's beyond the scope of the goals for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's say, you have created a magic function that do all your operation. The name of the function is `double allFunctions(double a, double b)`.

If problem is, the function have only 2 inputs. `a` and `b`, so the function know with which values it will be working. But what will it do with those `a` and `b`. Does this function have any clue? No, right? So, if you want to do all operation in one function than you need to set an extra parameter from which the function will be able to understand what to do with those `a` and `b`.

So, you magic function should be for example `double allFuncations(double a, double b, int operation)`. Now inside this function you can set condition that if `operation` is `1` then return `add` result and if its `2` then return `subtract` result and so on. So, how will you call this new function?

```
printf( "Addition: %.2lf\n", allFuncations(x,y, 1));//for addition
printf( "Substraction: %.2lf\n", allFuncations(x,y, 2));//for subtraction
```

By the way, you can even use `char` type data instead of `int` for the `operation` variable that will be more readable. for example:

new function?

```
printf( "Addition: %.2lf\n", allFuncations(x,y, '+'));//for addition
printf( "Substraction: %.2lf\n", allFuncations(x,y, '-'));//for subtraction
```

When your function definition will be `double allFunction(double a, double b, char operation)`

Finally, this is how you can do all operation in a single function. But there is nothing wrong if you create separate function for every operation. Nothing to feel guilty there. Beside, getting all result in one line may create less control on your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define NUMBER_OF_FUNCTIONS 4 //assuming add subtract multiply divide 
double[NUMBER_OF_FUNCTIONS] allFunctions(double x,double y) {
  double answer[NUMBER_OF_FUNCTIONS];
  int i = 0;
  answer[i++]=addition(x,y);
  answer[i++]=subtraction(x,y);
  answer[i++]=multiplication(x,y);
  answer[i++]=division(x,y);
  return answer;
}

// ...
  {
    double a[NUMBER_OF_FUNCTIONS] = allFunctions(x,y);
    printf("Addition: %2lf\nSubtraction: %2lf\nMultiplication: %2lf\nDivision: %2lf\n",*a,a[1],a[2],a[3]);
  }
```